# BindEvent binding own function

Tags: button, eventhandler

I need to change property of window when button gets pressed.
There  are pretty enough examples on Wolfram's website, but all they bind predefined function "Print[]" and I have no problems with binding Print function. But I can't bind something different.

I need call my own function and methods of Widgets.

This is a window whose property I want to change:

```
widget4 = Widget["TextPanel", {
"preferredSize" -> 
Widget["Dimension", {"width" -> 800, "height" -> 660}],
"contentType" -> "text/html",
"editable" -> False, "path" -> html1path}, Name -> "MainOutput"] 

 functio[]:=(Print["fffff"]);
```

This is my button:

```
html2path="some text which I want to change";
butto = Widget["Button", {
"Text" -> "Update",
BindEvent["Action",
Script[    {SetPropertyValue[{"MainOutput", "path"}, html2path] , 
  Print["fdfdf"], ref@InvokeMethod[{"Frame", "getX"}], functio[] } ]]
}]
```

I launch it all together so:

```
ref = GUIRun[ Widget["Frame", {widget4, butto}, Name -> "Frame" ]];
```

As result out of all my tries only function Print["fdfdf"] was called. 
[image]

I got stuck with it.   
Thanks in advance.

Comment: GUIKit has not been maintained for a long time and suffers from many bugs. You might like to try David Bailey's [super widget package](http://www.dbaileyconsultancy.co.uk/superwidgetpackage/superwidgetpackage.html) as an alternative. But bear in mind I say this having not seriously used either of them.

Comment: sadly, it seems it is not so new as well as GUIKit

Comment: Are you working in a version higher than 5? If so, I'd suggest dropping GUIkit and work with the dynamic controls introduced in version 6 and later.

Comment: I'm working in 9th Version. it's sad. Application would look better using GUIkit. It can render CSS. Until now I got this http://minus.com/ldan2YzBYKV5N . I'd not like to leave it.

Answer (score 2):

After trying to solve it for a day. I came to the point that looking for source code is necessary.

The most interesting files I found here:
/home/sh/po/mathematica_installed/AddOns/Packages/GUIKit/GUI/AuthorTools

(i.e. you need check this path "/AddOns/Packages/GUIKit/GUI/AuthorTools" in the folder where Mathematica is installed to)

These files have pretty good examples of Mathematica's GUIKit usage:

HelpBrowserSearchScriptCode.m 
DirectorySearchScriptCode.m  
DirectorySearch.m

They prove that GUIKit can work good.

The problem was that for changing GUI's elements Script which handle's button's pressing **MUST** be executed in the Java ATW  Thread.

So now I have such working code:

```
Needs["GUIKit`"];
ref = GUIRun[ 
Widget["Panel", {
 Widget["Button", {
  "text" -> "Run",
  BindEvent["action",
   Script[
    SetPropertyValue[{"button", "enabled"}, False, 
     InvokeThread -> "Dispatch"];

    SetPropertyValue[{"label", "text"}, 
     "New Text! Huuuraaaaaaaaaaa!!!!!!!!", 
     InvokeThread -> "Dispatch"];

    SetPropertyValue[{"button", "enabled"}, True, 
     InvokeThread -> "Dispatch"];
    ], 
   InvokeThread -> "New"]
  }, Name -> "button"],
Widget["Label", {
  "text" -> "Press Button to see changes      "
  }, Name -> "label"]
}]  ]
```

It's explained [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/GUIKit/tutorial/Threads.html) also.