# Could one compile a stand alone program from Mathematica and how to

Tags: programming

Last year, I start nearly from 0 to learn how to program and I have choosen to work with Mathematica. So this question is certainly naive but think of me as a beginner. I have understood how to make a cdf and I think to have learned their limitations. But I would like to know if I can make an standalone program with input --- say data --- and output from Mathematica and in the case of a positive answer --- even through compilation in C as long as I am no obliged to learn too much of it --- and in that case what is the procedure --- am I obliged to install some other softwares... For me the main point is the syntax.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/76335/27539 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37908/27539

Comment: This does not answer your question (hence is a comment), but for limited scope of functionality there is the `Compile` function. It has an option to compile to C.